# uiscrollview only allow scrolling back

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view that I would like to only allow the user to scroll back.  They press a button to make a selection and that scrolls forward, this part works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume back/forward refers to up and down. First, I'd save the scroll position any time a valid scroll occurs. So say you want to make it so the user cannot scroll up, only down. Whenever they finish scrolling down, the UIScrollViews scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: method will be called. I would set the delegate for the UIScrollView and implement that method. In that method set the contentOffset of the scrollview to your variable. Next, implement the delegate method scrollViewDidScroll: and check the new offset compared to your stored offset. If the y value of the new offset is greater than (or less than, depending on which way you are limiting the user), then manually set the scrollview's offset to the stored offset.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks.  I do mean left and right, a horizontal scroll.